# Jenkins : Add custom jar in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, nexus

I am trying to add custom jar which is not available in Maven repository. When I am executing in local I am pointing to the Jar path, So no issues. But when I execute with Jenkins I am facing issue as *Could not resolve dependencies for project*. Also it list down the two Jar file missing which I added custom.

So help me how to add the custom Jar wile executing using Jenkins. Also I am using Nexus for binary storage. After Jenkins executes successfully the image file will be posted to the nexus directory with versioning.

Comment: take a look at [this plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), we're using it on our project. is it what you need?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich. Thanks for your comment. I failed to add that Jenkins was installed in a server where I don't have admin permission to add global values. So it will be helpful if there is any method to access the jar in pom.xml after placing in Git or Nexus.

Comment: Install this jar into your repository manager and use as a usual dependency. That makes life easier...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1) If your have access to the local Nexus/Artifactory repo that your Jenkins uses you [can add the jar to that repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and it will be downloaded as normal.

2) You can have a local repository where you check the jar into SCM under your project.  You would then access it like this in your pom. See http://doduck.com/adding-local-jar-in-maven-local-repository/

```
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>localrepository</id>
         <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
```